# When I put async with BackgroundTimer.setTimeout to use await sleep() function in execution code, it does not run in the background, only foreground

Tags: react-native

I have a count variable, and after every second, it increments and consoles

```
let timeoutId = 0;

// start function
onStart={() => {
    timeoutId = BackgroundTimer.setTimeout(async () => {
              while(true)
              {
                setCount(prev => prev + 1);
                await sleep(1000);
              }
            }, 1000);
}}

// stop function
onStop={() => {
     BackgroundTimer.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
 }}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `setInterval`? It is already asynchronous in nature

Comment: I only want execution for once, not repeatedly

Comment: If you only want it to execute once, why do you have a while loop?

Comment: Oh, this is something else, I was trying to check my code, because I'm going to use while loop in my code, for background timer